# Ошибка при ожидании selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium

После использования `time.sleep(n)` появляется ошибка

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    print("Buy: " + str(elemGreen.text))
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 76, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: У меня однажды была похожая проблема с geckodriver, обновил драйвер и всё прошло) Попробуйте, может и с chromedriver тоже поможет)